# Layout not inflating correclty

Tags: android, android-fragments, layout-inflater

When I run my application, I get this error:

```
01-06 15:00:42.865: E/AndroidRuntime(24230): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-06 15:00:42.865: E/AndroidRuntime(24230): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.fotolife.app/com.fotolife.app.MainView}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class com.google.android.maps.MapView
01-06 15:00:42.865: E/AndroidRuntime(24230):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)
01-06 15:00:42.865: E/AndroidRuntime(24230):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
01-06 15:00:42.865: E/AndroidRuntime(24230):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
01-06 15:00:42.865: E/AndroidRuntime(24230):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
01-06 15:00:42.865: E/AndroidRuntime(24230):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-06 15:00:42.865: E/AndroidRuntime(24230):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-06 15:00:42.865: E/AndroidRuntime(24230):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
01-06 15:00:42.865: E/AndroidRuntime(24230):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-06 15:00:42.865: E/AndroidRuntime(24230):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-06 15:00:42.865: E/AndroidRuntime(24230):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1008)
01-06 15:00:42.865: E/AndroidRuntime(24230):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:775)
01-06 15:00:42.865: E/AndroidRuntime(24230):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-06 15:00:42.865: E/AndroidRuntime(24230): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class com.google.android.maps.MapView
01-06 15:00:42.865: E/AndroidRuntime(24230):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
01-06 15:00:42.865: E/AndroidRuntime(24230):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
01-06 15:00:42.865: E/AndroidRuntime(24230):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
01-06 15:00:42.865: E/AndroidRuntime(24230):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
01-06 15:00:42.865: E/AndroidRuntime(24230):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
01-06 15:00:42.865: E/AndroidRuntime(24230):    at com.fotolife.app.Map.onCreateView(Map.java:12)
01-06 15:00:42.865: E/AndroidRuntime(24230):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:871)
01-06 15:00:42.865: E/AndroidRuntime(24230):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1083)
01-06 15:00:42.865: E/AndroidRuntime(24230):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:635)
01-06 15:00:42.865: E/AndroidRuntime(24230):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1431)
01-06 15:00:42.865: E/AndroidRuntime(24230):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:523)
01-06 15:00:42.865: E/AndroidRuntime(24230):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1178)
01-06 15:00:42.865: E/AndroidRuntime(24230):    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5201)
01-06 15:00:42.865: E/AndroidRuntime(24230):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2073)
01-06 15:00:42.865: E/AndroidRuntime(24230):    ... 11 more
01-06 15:00:42.865: E/AndroidRuntime(24230): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
01-06 15:00:42.865: E/AndroidRuntime(24230):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
01-06 15:00:42.865: E/AndroidRuntime(24230):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
01-06 15:00:42.865: E/AndroidRuntime(24230):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
01-06 15:00:42.865: E/AndroidRuntime(24230):    ... 24 more
01-06 15:00:42.865: E/AndroidRuntime(24230): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MapViews can only be created inside instances of MapActivity.
01-06 15:00:42.865: E/AndroidRuntime(24230):    at com.google.android.maps.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:291)
01-06 15:00:42.865: E/AndroidRuntime(24230):    at com.google.android.maps.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:264)
01-06 15:00:42.865: E/AndroidRuntime(24230):    at com.google.android.maps.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:247)
01-06 15:00:42.865: E/AndroidRuntime(24230):    ... 27 more
```

It says there error is at line 12 of this file:

```
package com.fotolife.app;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class Map extends Fragment {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.map, container, false);
    }

}
```

Line 12 is the: return inflater.inflate.....

and here is the xml file that the fragment is supposed to be inflating:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:apiKey="@string/maps_api_key"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your error:

`01-06 15:00:42.865: E/AndroidRuntime(24230): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MapViews can only be created inside instances of MapActivity.`

You can't use `MapView` with fragments, since to use fragments your Activity needs to be a subclass of `Activity` (v11+) or `FragmentActivity`, but to use `MapView` your activity must be a subclass of `MapActivity`.

If you want to use maps and fragments together you'll need to use the [Google Play Services Maps API](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/maps.html) which contains a [`MapFragment`](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment.html) (v11+) or [`SupportMapFragment`](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment.html).

Comment: The SupportMapFragment fixed it! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I've never used the Google Maps Android API before, but looking at your stacktrace:

```
01-06 15:00:42.865: E/AndroidRuntime(24230): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MapViews can only be created inside instances of MapActivity.
```

Your activity needs to extend `MapActivity`. Perhaps you should use the new V2 API if you want to use fragments. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/

As your layout contains just a `MapView`, have you considered using a `SupportMapFragment` instead:

```
<fragment
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

or

```
SupportMapFragment f = new SupportMapFragment();
getSupportFragmentManager().beingTransaction()
    .add(android.R.id.content, f)
    .commit();
```

See the documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment

Comment: I am using v2, but I need to be able to switch between different fragments.